# C# MVC - Passing object with list of another object inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, post

I want to post an object that has list of another object inside, `MVC` is receiving the object as null.

**MVC Post**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ObjectWithList objectWithList) { 
  // While debugging objectWithList has its properties null
}
```

**ObjectWithList**

```
public class ObjectWithList
{
    public List<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
    public AnotherFoo AnotherFoo { get; set; }
}
```

Foo and AntoherFoo are classes with normal properties, like string, etc.

Using Postman I POST:
Headers: Content-Type as application/json
Body (raw):

```
{
    "Foo": [
        {
          "Name": "test"
        },
        {
         "Name": "test"
        }
   ],
   "AnotherFoo": {
       "Name": "asd",
       "Email": "asd@asd.com"
   }
}
```

If I just pass "Foo" empty:

```
{
    "Foo": [
            {}
    ]
    ...
```

it works, (fills AnotherFoo). But as soon as i try to pass something inside Foo, MVC gets everything as null.

I'm correctly naming the properties of Foo and AnotherFoo on the JSON

Comment: Have you tried the **[FromBody]** attribute on the controller action?

Comment: [Model binding JSON POSTs in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [FromBody] attribute on the controller action?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([FromBody]ObjectWithList objectWithList) { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var foos = {
 "Foo": [
        {
          "Name": "test"
        },
        {
         "Name": "test"
        }
   ],
   "AnotherFoo": {
       "Name": "asd",
       "Email": "asd@asd.com"
   }
};

$.ajax({
    url: "YourUrl",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ objectWithList: foos })
}).done(function(result){
//do something
});
```